# Retrieve Sorted Column Value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sorting, sql-server-2012

**What i have:**

I have a Column

```
ID  SerialNo
1   101
2   102
3   103
4   104
5   105
6   116
7   117
8   118
9   119
10  120
```

These are just the 10 dummy rows. The actual table has over 100 000 rows.

**What I Want to get:**

A method or formula like any sorting technique which could return me the starting and ending element of [SerialNo] Column for every sub-series. For example

**Expected Result: 101-105, 115-120**

The comma separation in the above result is not important, only the starting and ending elements are important.

**What I have tried:**

I did it by PL/SQL programming, by running a loop in which I’m getting the starting and ending elements getting stored in a TABLE.
But due to no. of rows (over 100 000) the query execution is taking around 2 minutes.

I have also searched about some sorting techniques for the SQL Server but I found nothing. Because rendering every row will take twice the time then a sorting algorithm

Comment: what is range to define sub series?

Comment: Look for gaps and islands http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands

Comment: Why would your second range be 115-120 and not 116-120?

Comment: range could be any.... in hundreds in thousands @Swapnil

Comment: My typing mistake@Rich Benner

Comment: Please clarify the definition of range. " in hundreds in thousands" does not say much. Is the number of sub-series elements constant? Is it based on ID column? Does the answer provided by @Swapnil do what you want?

Comment: This looks a gaps and islands problem -- so searching with that should give you different options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finding the start and end of each series is quite straightforward:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null, SerialNo int not null)
insert into @t(ID,SerialNo) values
(1 ,101),    (2 ,102),    (3 ,103),
(4 ,104),    (5 ,105),    (6 ,116),
(7 ,117),    (8 ,118),    (9 ,119),
(10,120)

;With Starts as (
    select t1.SerialNo,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.SerialNo) as rn
    from
        @t t1
            left join
        @t t1_no
            on t1.SerialNo = t1_no.SerialNo + 1
    where t1_no.ID is null
), Ends as (
    select t1.SerialNo,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.SerialNo) as rn
    from
        @t t1
            left join
        @t t1_no
            on t1.SerialNo = t1_no.SerialNo - 1
    where t1_no.ID is null
)
select
    s.SerialNo as StartSerial,
    e.SerialNo as EndSerial
from
    Starts s
        inner join
    Ends e
        on s.rn = e.rn
```

The logic being that a `Start` is a row where there is no row that has the `SerialNo` one less than the current row, and an `End` is a row where there is no row that has the `SerialNo` one more than the current row.

This may still perform poorly if there is no index on the `SerialNo` column.

Results:

```
StartSerial EndSerial
----------- -----------
101         105
116         120
```

Which is hopefully acceptable since you didn't seem to care what the specific results look like. It's also keeping things set-based.

Comment: Worked for me..! Thanks @damien_the_unbeliever

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every sub series should contain 5 records, I got expected result using below sql. I hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @subSeriesRange INT=5;

CREATE TABLE #Temp(ID INT,SerialNo INT);

INSERT INTO  #Temp VALUES(1,101),
(2,102),
(3,103),
(4,104),
(5,105),
(6,116),
(7,117),
(8,115),
(9,119),
(10,120);

SELECT STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(CASE ID%@subSeriesRange WHEN 1 THEN ',' ELSE '-' END,SerialNo)
        FROM #Temp
        WHERE ID%@subSeriesRange = 1 OR ID%@subSeriesRange=0
        ORDER BY ID
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''
        );

DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

Comment: Given absence of "sub series" definition, your answer works.

Comment: the range here for sub-series could be any.... in hundreds in thousands @Alex thnx

Comment: Hi @Priyank, added subSeriesRange variable to define range.